# Как отправлять данные о местоположении на сервер

Tags: java, android

Написал программу, которая определяет координаты местонахождения, но как отправлять данные на сервер не знаю.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        // Get the location manager
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        // Define the criteria how to select the locatioin provider -> use
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
        provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // Initialize the location fields
        if (location != null) {
            System.out.println("Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");
            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latituteField.setText("Location not available");
            longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 400, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enabled new provider " + provider, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Disabled provider " + provider Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: весьма странный вопрос... Я умею делать чай - вот посмотрите, а как делается кофе - не знаю.

Comment: можете помочь?)))

Comment: @breddy если Вы хотите, чтобы Ваш комментарий дошел до конкретного человека, то комментарий должен начинаться с @, а после без пробелов имя участника SO, к которому Вы хотите обратиться. Иначе Вы адресуете комментарии только автору вопроса

Comment: Имхо, я согласен с предыдущим оратором, что очень странный вопрос

Comment: А как сервер принимает данные?